# Alternative function to byteValue java in php

Tags: java, php

Any one know is there any byteValue function in php similar to Java?

Say for example:

```
Integer sampleInt=new Integer(132);
System.out.println(sampleInt.byteValue());
```

> returns **-124**

Same thing to be done in PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.byteValue()` in java is casting the type to a byte, this casting can be represented in pp by doing:

```
$in = 132;
$out = $in & 0xff;
if($out > 127)
    $out -= 256;
echo $out;
```

1. We use byte masks to cut away the left bits of the int.
2. Then we check if its greater than 127
3. Then we subtract 256, so the overflow property of java is simulated

Answer (score 1):

Use the ord function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php

Example:

```
<?php
 $var = "test";

 for($i = 0; $i < strlen($var); $i++)
 {
    echo ord($var[$i])."<br/>";
 }
?>
```